# Aura Component shows correctly in preview but not in real experience site

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Im trying to display a field of the current ID and it works perfectly in experience site preview but doesnt render in the actual site.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! not( empty( v.objId ) ) }">
 <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.objId}" objectApiName="customobj__c">
 <lightning:outputField fieldName="child__c" variant="label-hidden" class="custom"/>
```

Obj id is sent correctly in both cases, i have checked it in system debugger.

Answer (score 1):

It was a profile issue. The account being used didn't have permissions to view the field.